# Connection refused Maas Web UI

Tags: networking, maas

I have a problem with getting MaaS to work. At first I installed through snap, and met some errors, but figured it was due to being an experimental build. So now I have installed through packages (https://docs.maas.io/2.4/en/installconfig-package-install)

It seemed to go well, but now when I try to connect to my web interface, I get connection refused.
I am new to linux, so ELI5 type explanations for stuff would be appreciated :)

Comment: hello, could you provide output of "sudo netstat -ntlp" and "iptables -L"?

Comment: What AtomiX84 said is spot on - these commands help see what ports are open (what's listening) and that it's not being blocked by firewall

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/9fBbgNp.png
Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and what solved it is us changing the hostname our old hostname had an (_) in it that was causing some problems and after removing that it worked.